# Adding data in recyclerview dynamically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to save data in recyclerview using ArrayList dynamically, but I'm having a problem.
Every time I add data in recycler view, it replaces the previous data and shows only the last data I have entered.
I'm passing that value using SharedPreference to next activity like this

```
 builder.setNeutralButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

            size = sp.getInt("size",size);
            size = size+1;
            editor.putString("name"+size , scanResult);
            editor.putInt("size" , size);
            editor.commit();

            finish();
        }
   });
```

**This is the activity where I'm adding data in ArrayList;**

> Results.java

```
 ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

 pref = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,MODE_PRIVATE);
 int size = pref.getInt("size",0);
 String scanResult = pref.getString("name"+size,"");
 data.add(scanResult);
 listView_result = findViewById(R.id.listResult);
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new 
 LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
 listView_result.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
 ResultAdapter adapter = new ResultAdapter(Results.this, data);
 listView_result.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**This the adapter for recyclerview**

> ResultAdapter.java

```
 public class ResultAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultAdapter.ViewHolder> {

     private Context context;
     private ArrayList<String> code;

     ResultAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<String> code) {
         this.context = context;
         this.code = code;
     }

     @NonNull
     @Override
     public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_text , parent , false);

          return new ViewHolder(v);
      }

      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) 
      {
          holder.txt.setText( code.get(position));

      }

      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
          return code.size();
      }

      class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
          TextView txt;
          ViewHolder(View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
          txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_list);
       }
 }

}
```

Comment: I guess you'er re initializing Arraylist each time a new object has to be added.You should keep "ArrayList<String> data;" as a field and initialize it only once in constructor then use it in your update function as data.add(scanResult) .Or can you share Result.Java class

Comment: Please add your activity code.

Comment: You always reinitiate adapter and also the RecyclerView every time instead of adding an item on the adapter. Would you please provide the full activity code related to recyclerview update and create. Then we can able find and provide the possible solution.

Comment: problem solved thanks for your reply everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int size = pref.getInt("size",0);
String scanResult = pref.getString("name"+size,"");
data.add(scanResult);
```

Above should be

```
int size = pref.getInt("size",0);
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  String scanResult = pref.getString("name"+i,"");
  data.add(scanResult);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot you have solved my problem i've been searching for it more than a week thanks a lot